# Preserving tar file permissions in ant task for multiple files using tarfileset

Tags: linux, unix, ant, build, file-permissions

I have a list of files for which I need to preserve the permissions during the ant task. I don have to preserve permssions for the rest of the files within 'src' directory. I realized that the only way to do this is using tarfileset's filemode attribute. Currently I am excluding the list of files in the first tarfileset and including them the second time with the permissions (to avoid duplicate files with different permssions) as given below:

```
<tar basedir="src" destfile="myzip.tar.gz" compression="gzip">
     <tarfileset dir="com/foo/bar">
        <exclude name="com/foo/bar/script1.sh"/>
        <exclude name="com/foo/bar/script2.sh"/>
     </tarfileset>
     <tarfileset dir="com/foo/bar" filemode="755">
        <include name="com/foo/bar/script1.sh"/>
        <include name="com/foo/bar/script2.sh"/>
     </tarfileset>
</tar>
```

I have to first exclude all the files and then again include them with the permissions which seems kind of redundant. Is this approach correct or is there a better way by which I can preserve the permissions of the list of files.

Note: I don't have just 2 files to for which I need to preserve the permissions. The list is quite big.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.